# jquery date picker with editable dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I was using this solution given here for my editable dropdownlist

[Editable DropdownList](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290218/Custom-ASP-NET-Editable-DropDownList) . It works fine. However i added a date field and tried to use the JQUERY UI datepicker. These two does not seem to work together. As soon as i add the jquery-ui-version.js file, the editable dropdownlist does not work. So something in the js file messes up the dropdownlist. Whats the best way to start figuring out a fix for this? Is there a simple version of jquery datepicker that i can use?

Or is there another solution for an editable dropdownlist in asp.net?

Thanks.

Yes you are right.The files that are required by editable dropdownlist are (it uses some components of jquery UI)

```
              jquery.ui.core.js
              jquery.ui.widget.js
              jquery.ui.button.js
              jquery.ui.position.js
              jquery.ui.autocomplete.js
              jquery.ui.combobox.js
```

The main UI js is

```
              jquery-ui-1.10.1.js
```

and this is the one that makes editable dropdownlist fail.

Comment: It seems like Editable DropdownList depends on JQuery UI. Probably you are using a newer version of jquery UI that is conflicting with the old one. Or maybe Calling JQuery UI twice with undesired efects.

Comment: If you downloaded JQuery UI full then it is overlaping with the previous jquery UI components. I suggest that you remove the old jquery.ui ones and just leave jquery-ui-1.10.1.js

Comment: but does jquery-ui-1.10.1.js contain the required js files for editable dropdownlist???

Comment: that does not appear to work..i removed all the jquery.ui.*.js files and just had one jquery.ui01.10.1.js

Comment: datepicker should work without the jquery-ui-1.10.1.js, all it needs is ui core and  effects core (which I think is optional) which the editable drop down uses as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Editable DropdownList depends on JQuery UI. You are already including many JQuery UI components.

You might have probably downloaded a full version of JQuery UI including the same components already included before.

Go to http://jqueryui.com/download/ and build the JQuery UI Bundle with all the features you need plus datepicker.

Then remove the old jquery.ui components and just include the new download. Also replace the css and images with the new ones.

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work..I built my own custom jquery ui as specified by editable ddl(including datepicker) I also added jquery-ui.combobox which is not part of jquery library...

Comment: one thing i can think of is,editable ddl website say, the js shud be of a particular order...an my custom jqueryui has this comment in the beginning...

Comment: *  Includes: jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.ui.position.js, jquery.ui.autocomplete.js, jquery.ui.button.js, jquery.ui.datepicker.js, jquery.ui.menu.js    *  so wonder if the order is an issue....